# Javascript context in inner class object

Tags: javascript

Prior to using ES6 we could instantiate a "class" like so...

```
var Animal = function(){}
```

and then...

```
var dog = new Animal()
```

the context within the "class" will be the class (instance) itself

```
var Animal = function( name ){

   this.name = name;

   this.getName = function(){

      // the context here (this) is the class (Animal)
      return this.name; // works well

   }

}
```

The question is, if I wouldn't want to pollute the root scope and use sub-objects, for various uses, then the context would become the object in which the function is being kept

```
var Animal = function( name ){

   this.utilities = {

      this.getName : function(){

         // the context here is the 'utilities' object so...
         return this.name // wouldn't work

      }

   }

}
```

of course we could always use something in the form of

```
dog.utilities.getName.call(dog)
```

but this would be kind of long and uncomfortable...

is there a way to create the 'utilities' object and apply the context to all of its functions to point back to the root scope? without having to use `call` and `apply` every time? (an answer without using ES6 would be great...)

Comment: *"the context within the "class" will be the class itself"* No. First, `this` isn't "context." `this` is just `this`, which is effectively just a special function argument. Second, `this` doesn't refer to the class (e.g., the constructor function), it refers to the **instance** (object) created by `new`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the input, point taken. do you have an answer?

Comment: @Rajesh I used to do that, but then all instances share this same function, or is it different from using `Animal.constructor.prototype` ? maybe its my mistake...

Comment: @levi: Why yes, I do; I was in fact typing it.

Comment: @Rajesh I was using this technique `(self = this)` the problem was when using constructor prototypes it sometimes changes the `self` context and it caused mixups... if all else fails I would probably go with that, but I was looking for a way to change the `this` itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to ensure that `this` is what you want it to be in the various `utilities` functions is to use arrow functions for them, since arrow functions close over the `this` where they're defined:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.utilities = {
      getName: () => {       // This is an arrow function
        return this.name;    //
      }                      //
    };
  }
}
const dog = new Animal("dog");
console.log(dog.utilities.getName()); // "dog"
```

This is basically the ES2015+ version of the old `var t = this;` solution:

```js
function Animal(name) {
  var t = this;
  this.name = name;
  this.utilities = {
    getName() {
      return t.name;
    }
  };
}
var dog = new Animal("dog");
console.log(dog.utilities.getName()); // "dog"
```

In both cases, this means that you're creating new function objects for each individual instance of `Animal` (the *code* will be shared between those objects, but the objects are distinct). That's fine unless there are going to be a **lot** of `Animal` instances.

Alternately, you could have a helper that you pass the instance to:

```js
const Animal = (function() {
  class Utilities {
    constructor(animal) {
      this.a = animal;
    }
    getName() {
      return this.a.name;
    }
  }
  
  class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
      this.name = name;
      this.utilities = new Utilities(this);
    }
  }
  return Animal;
})();
const dog = new Animal("dog");
console.log(dog.utilities.getName()); // "dog"
```

or

```js
var Animal = (function() {
  function Utilities(animal) {
    this.a = animal;
  }
  Utilities.prototype.getName = function getName() {
    return this.a.name;
  };
  
  return function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.utilities = new Utilities(this);
  }
})();
var dog = new Animal("dog");
console.log(dog.utilities.getName()); // "dog"
```

...which lets utilities reuse its function objects via `Utilities.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks T.J - I was looking for a solution which isn't ES6... the first code snippet looks good tough, is there a way to achieve the same behavior using the old method? ...

Comment: @levi: Ah, that wasn't clear from your question. Yes, via `bind`. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks, I know already know of the `var t = this` and `new Utilities(this)` solutions... the first one can cause mixups when declaring `constructor.prototype` functions, the `t` can get mixed up, the second technique is not as 'elegant' ... the first bit of code you wrote (ES6) is just beautiful, but if only this worked with ES5, maybe its time to upgrade...

Comment: @levi: *"the first one can cause mixups when declaring constructor.prototype functions"* Not just "can." You can't use it with functions on the prototype. That's just as true of the arrow functions in the first snippet above; they are, effectively, the same solution. I've edited to make that clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the following:

```
var utilities = function (context) {
    return {
        getName: function () {
            console.log(context.name)
        }
    }
}

var Animal = function( name ){
   this.name = name
   this.utilities = utilities.call(null, this)
}

var dog = new Animal('dog')
dog.utilities.getName()
```

But, if you are okay doing this: `dog.getName()` instead of `dog.utilities.getName()` then you might have a cleaner solution (IMO) as follows:

```
var Animal = function( name ){
   this.name = name
}

var utilities = {
    getName: function () {
        console.log(this.name)
    }
};

Object.assign(Animal.prototype, utilities)

var dog = new Animal('dog')
dog.getName()
```

Let me know if that works. Thanks.

NEW ANSWER:

```
var UTILITIES = {
    getName: function () {
        console.log(this.self.name)
    }
}

var Animal = function (name) {
    this.name = name
    this.utilities = Object.create(UTILITIES, {
        self: {
            value: this
        }
    })
}

var dog = new Animal('dog')
dog.utilities.getName()
```

Variation includes the use of a 'self' attribute which points to the instance of interest. Now, this `could` look more intuitive.

Comment: The first snippet looks a bit like T.Js answer (see the last snippet) if there are no other solutions I would refer to that, but I'm hoping to get an even cleaner solution, something in the form of T.Js first snippet but written in something prior to ES6

Comment: `this.utilities = utilities.call(null, this)` or, you know, `this.utilities = utilities(this)` (which is exactly the same thing).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that is perfectly right for the first snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getter methods. I find them very useful for cases where I need formatted value. This way, the utilities/ logic is only known to this class and is not exposed outside.

```js
function Person(fname, lname) {
  var _fname = fname;
  var _lname = lname;
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
    get: function(){
      return _fname + ' ' + _lname
    }
  });
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'firstName', {
    get: function(){
      return _fname
    },
    set: function(value) {
      _fname = value;
    }
  });
  
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'lastName', {
    get: function(){
      return _lname
    },
    set: function(value) {
      _lname = value;
    }
  });
}

var person = new Person('hello', 'world');
console.log(person.fullName);

person.firstName = 'Hello';
console.log(person.fullName);

person.lastName = 'World'
console.log(person.fullName);
```

Comment: **Note:** If you think this answer has anything incorrect/ not required, please comment along with your vote. That would really help everyone.

Comment: This is really nice and using Object.defineProperty is a good convention, what the browser "can i use" for that? ... but eventually I wasn't looking for a way to use either class global scope declarations or properties, but a way to call a function within an object with the instance context... thanks anyway